# No module named djangoapp.app.context_processors

Tags: python, django

I have added the following module to my default_settings.py and I get the following errors am adding pdf app to my site allowing the user to print webpage as a pdf.

```
`Exception Value:   

Error importing request processor module djangoapp.app.context_processors: "No module named djangoapp.app.context_processors"`
```

`Exception Location:    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/context.py in get_standard_processors, line 84`

This is my default_settings

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'djangoapp.app.context_processors.media_url',
    'convergedsecurity.core.UserMessages.userMessageList',
    'convergedsecurity.core.context_processors.standard_navigation_data',
    'convergedsecurity.core.context_processors.application_info',

)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a custom djangoapp app in your django project. And it should contain media_url context processor, but it wasn't found in that app (or the whole app wasn't found).

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say `djangoapp.context_processors.media_url` and accidently added `djangoapp.app.context_processors.media_url`?

Comment: I have added this module. `django_pdf.context_processors.check_format` and they recommended  `'djangoapp.app.context_processors.media_url',`

Comment: Where they recommend this? https://github.com/directeur/django-pdf They dont have any mention about media_url,

Comment: Can django-pdf print images in the pdf?

Comment: Comments isn't a place to ask such question thats not related to original question in any way.

Answer (score 0):

From your comments, it looks like you were following some instruction that was encouraging you to write your own context processor (possibly adding some sort of information relating to media to the context).

Often in write-ups, they will use `djangoapp` as the placeholder for your project name, and here it is suggesting a context_processor in your app within your project.

However, as Aldarund pointed out, it doesn't seem to have any mention of this context processor in the django_pdf documentation.

Try removing it, and see if things work out alright. If not, you may have to write a custom context processor. They are actually surprisingly easy to write though.

Here are some in the Django source so you can see how they are written: [Django's Context Processors](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/context_processors.py)

Comment: When I take out django_pdf.context_processors.check_format my site works but as soon as I add the ?format=pdf it gives me 
`Internal Server Error`